# PYSPARK : casting string to float when reading a csv file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading a csv file to dataframe

```
datafram = spark.read.csv(fileName, header=True)
```

but the data type in datafram  is String, I want to change data type to float. Is there any way to do this efficiently?

Comment: you could specify the `schema=`

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward way to achieve this is by casting.

```
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("float", col("column").cast("double"))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do the casting when reading the CSV, you can use the `inferSchema` argument when reading the data. Let's try with a a small test csv file:

```
$ cat ../data/test.csv
a,b,c,d
5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0
2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0
4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0
```

Now, if we read it as you did, we will have string values:

```
>>> df_csv = spark.read.csv("../data/test.csv", header=True)
>>> print(df_csv.dtypes)
[('a', 'string'), ('b', 'string'), ('c', 'string'), ('d', 'string')]
```

However, if we set `inferSchema` to `True`, it will correctly identify them as doubles:

```
>>> df_csv2 = spark.read.csv("../data/test.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
>>> print(df_csv2.dtypes)
[('a', 'double'), ('b', 'double'), ('c', 'double'), ('d', 'double')]
```

However, this approach requires another run over the data. You can find more information on the [DataFrameReader CSV documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader).